# Авторизация на сервисе mega.nz

Tags: visual-c++

Привет. Пишу ПО на С++ под сервис MEGA https://mega.nz/
ОС: Windows

Задался таким вопросом...
Там один раз авторизовался, и можно потоком заливать файлы?
или как FTP, если соединение прервалось, то заново нужно авторизовываться?

И ещё вопрос... возможна одновременная авторизация на 3 компьютерах по ос windows
c одним аккаунтом? Все это надо для потоковой загрузки в облако фото и видео.

Comment: Это скорее надо адресовать в документацию и/или поддержку Меги.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку